# Ebay API - Scrolling to load more items loads the same data

Tags: android, ebay-api

I'm not sure what is making this act the way that it's acting but I have recently changed my search method from `findItemsByKeywords` to `findItemsAdvanced` [source](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) .

Then I added this line here to my request along side my normal search keywords query.

```
request.categoryId = category;
```

for some reason, if I request a specific category for my search keyword to be searched in, along side my normal search keyword, it loads absolutely fine for the first initial load, but then when I scroll to the bottom for more items to be loaded, it just displays the same data that has already been loaded.

This does not happen if I just request one of the 2, not both at the same time.

**EDIT**: My theory is maybe it's something to do with my `onScrollStateChanged` at the bottom of my class, but I can't seem to find the issue.

**EDIT 2:** This seems to be only happening if I request `request.categoryId = category;` and `request.keywords = searchKeywords;` together. I can request other combination like `request.sortOrder = SortOrderType.END_TIME_SOONEST;` e.t.c with either of the 2, just not both of them together.

Here's my class, maybe someone will be able to guide me, thanks.

```
public class CitroenC1 extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener {

private static final String TAG = CitroenC1.class.getSimpleName();

static final int DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE = 25;

private String nothing = "";
private String category = "9801";
private int lastItem = 0;
private int totalItemCount = 0;

private String searchKeywords;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    String keywords = ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.C1)).getText()
            .toString();

    searchKeywords = keywords;

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);



    // make a search
    findItemsAdvanced(1, DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE, true);
}

// asynchronously trigger findItemsByKeywords call
private void findItemsAdvanced(int pageNum, int entriesPerPage,
        final boolean newSearch) {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...",
            "Retrieving data...", true, true);

    if (newSearch) {
        // reset
        lastItem = 0;
        totalItemCount = 0;
    }

    // build a request object
    FindItemsAdvancedRequest request = new FindItemsAdvancedRequest();

            //Here
    request.keywords = searchKeywords;
    request.categoryId = category;

    PaginationInput pi = new PaginationInput();
    pi.pageNumber = pageNum;
    pi.entriesPerPage = entriesPerPage;
    request.paginationInput = pi;

    // show fixed price and auction item only
    ItemFilter itemFilter = new ItemFilter();
    itemFilter.name = ItemFilterType.LISTING_TYPE;
    itemFilter.value = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemFilter.value.add("FixedPrice");
    itemFilter.value.add("Auction");
    request.itemFilter = new ArrayList<ItemFilter>();
    request.itemFilter.add(itemFilter);

    // Get shared client
    FindingServicePortType_SOAPClient client = FindingServiceClient
            .getSharedClient();
    client.setDebug(true);

    // make API call and register callbacks
    client.findItemsAdvanced(request,
            new SOAPServiceCallback<FindItemsAdvancedResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(
                        FindItemsAdvancedResponse responseObject) {
                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }

                    if (responseObject.ack == AckValue.SUCCESS) { // handle
                                                                    // sucessful
                                                                    // response
                        SearchResult searchResult = responseObject.searchResult;
                        if (newSearch) {
                            List<SearchItem> items = (searchResult.item != null) ? searchResult.item
                                    : new ArrayList<SearchItem>();
                            ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(
                                    getActivity(), R.layout.row, items);
                            CitroenC1.this.setListAdapter(itemAdapter);
                        } else {
                            if (searchResult.item != null) {
                                ItemAdapter itemAdapter = (ItemAdapter) CitroenC1.this
                                        .getListAdapter();
                                itemAdapter.items.addAll(searchResult.item);
                                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                    } else { // handle response resident error
                        String errorMessage = responseObject.errorMessage.error
                                .get(0).message;
                        ALog.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable error, String errorMessage) { // http
                                                                                // or
                                                                                // parsing
                                                                                // error
                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onSOAPFault(Object soapFault) { // soap fault
                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }

                    com.leansoft.nano.soap12.Fault fault = (com.leansoft.nano.soap12.Fault) soapFault;
                    Reasontext reasonText = fault.reason.text.get(0);

                    ALog.e(TAG, reasonText.value);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), reasonText.value,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            });
}

private class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchItem> {

    private List<SearchItem> items;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<SearchItem> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        final SearchItem item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
            TextView bidType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bids);
            TextView timeleft = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeleft);

            if (title != null) {
                title.setText(item.title);
            }

            Amount convertedCurrentPrice = item.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice;
            price.setText("£"
                    + eBayUtil.formatCurrencyToString(
                            convertedCurrentPrice.value, nothing));

            String listingType = item.listingInfo.listingType;
            if (listingType.equalsIgnoreCase("FixedPrice")
                    || listingType.equalsIgnoreCase("StoreInventory")) {
                bidType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bin_clear);

                bidType.setText("");
            } else {
                bidType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_blue_pixel);
                bidType.setText(item.sellingStatus.bidCount + " bids");
            }

            Duration duration = item.sellingStatus.timeLeft;
            if (duration.getDays() == 0 && duration.getHours() == 0
                    && duration.getMinutes() < 10) {
                timeleft.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                timeleft.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            timeleft.setText(eBayUtil.formatDuration(duration));

            WebImageView image = (WebImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.gallery_icon);
            if (image != null) {
                if (item.galleryURL != null) {
                    image.setImageUrl(item.galleryURL);
                    image.loadImage();
                } else {
                    image.setNoImageDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
                }
            }

            // once clicked, navigate to item details page
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(item.itemId, v
                    .getContext()));
        }

        return v;
    }
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private String mItemId;
    private Context mCxt;

    OnItemClickListener(String itemId, Context cxt) {
        mItemId = itemId;
        mCxt = cxt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ALog.d(TAG, "onItemClick at item " + mItemId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mCxt, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ITEM_ID", mItemId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

// for dynamic pagination
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
        int totalCount) {

    lastItem = firstVisible + visibleCount;
    totalItemCount = totalCount;
}

// for dynamic pagination
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

        boolean loadMore = lastItem >= totalItemCount;

        if (loadMore) {
            int nextPage = totalItemCount / DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE + 1;
            findItemsAdvanced(nextPage, DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE, false);

        }

    }

}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your code is separated on different files and this is just for demonstration.

private int lastItem = 0;
private int totalItemCount = 0;

You use those fields to know from where to update.

Your onScroll that updates them gets called before, each time the user scrolls.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
    int totalCount) {

lastItem = firstVisible + visibleCount;
totalItemCount = totalCount;
}
```

And when the scrolls stops or in other words SCROLL_STATE_IDLE those params get updated, so you just need to put either your update evaluation under OnScroll or you put your request code inside the OnScrollStateChanged.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
    int totalCount) {

lastItem = firstVisible + visibleCount;
totalItemCount = totalCount;
boolean loadMore = lastItem >= totalItemCount;

    if (loadMore) {
        int nextPage = totalItemCount / DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE + 1;
        findItemsAdvanced(nextPage, DEFAULT_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE, false);

    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know, if does not work log your params lastItem on the onScrollState and when you request your next page.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with my onScroll or OnScrollStateChanged. That's why I am confused because it works like it should when I use 1 of the 2, not both request.keywords = searchKeywords; and request.categoryId = category;. When I use both, the first search works perfectly, then I scroll down to the bottom to load more, it just retrieves the same data.  Then all I have do to fix this is remove one the request calls, but it's vital I have both of them. I've just tried what you have put in your answer and it does not work. Could you demonstrate how I can log my last item?

Comment: P.S - I say "I don't think it's anything to do with my onScroll or OnScrollStateChanged" because it works when I just call one request, not both, maybe it's something like a bug with the eBay API or something? really strange.